# shopify uninstall app webhook is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, webhooks

In my server.js file, I register the app/uninstalled webhook inside the afterAuth function like this:

```
const response = await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.register({
      shop,
      accessToken,
      path: "/webhooks",
      topic: "APP_UNINSTALLED",
      apiVersion: ApiVersion.October20,
      webhookHandler: (topic, shop, body) => {
        //console.log(topic, shop,body);
        delete ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop];
      },
    });
```

I am listening to route like this

```
router.post("/webhooks", appUninstallWebhook, async (ctx) => {
try {
  await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process(ctx.req, ctx.res);
  console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${error}`);
}
```

});

I see the webhook successfully being registered, however when I delete the app running locally on ngrok in my test Shopify store, I do not see that webhook being triggered.

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Hello mate! Did you get past this one? I'm stuck on the exact same thing

Comment: @DanTurner Nope. You can use this approach. This works

const response = await registerWebhook({
  shop,
  accessToken,
  address: `${HOST}/webhooks/app/uninstalled`,
  topic: "APP_UNINSTALLED",
  apiVersion: API_VERSION
});

And then configure the route

router.post("/webhooks/app/uninstalled", webhook, async (ctx) => {
  try {
    console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${error}`);
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it working but I got a workaround using another approach.

```js
const response = await registerWebhook({
  shop,
  accessToken,
  address: `${HOST}/webhooks/app/uninstalled`,
  topic: "APP_UNINSTALLED",
  apiVersion: API_VERSION
});
```

And then configure the route

```js
router.post("/webhooks/app/uninstalled", webhook, async (ctx) => {
  try {
    console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${error}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the `registerWebhook` coming from?

Comment: From `Shopify.Webhooks.Registry` like in:  `await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.register({path: "/api/webhooks",topic, accessToken, shop,});`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register `APP_UNINSTALLED` webhook in /auth/callback route of your shopify app i.e during oauth process register your webhook.

Sample code:

```
app.get('/auth/callback', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const shopSession = await Shopify.Auth.validateAuthCallback(req, res, req.query);
        const { shop, accessToken } = shopSession;

        const response = await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.register({
            path: '/api/webhooks',
            topic: 'APP_UNINSTALLED',
            accessToken: accessToken,
            shop: shop,
        });

        console.log("response", response)

        if (!response['APP_UNINSTALLED'].success) {
            console.log(
                `Failed to register APP_UNINSTALLED webhook: ${response.result}`
            );
        }


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

app.post("/api/webhooks", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process(req, res);
        console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
        res.status(200).send();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${error}`);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work properly after I noticed the line "app.use(express.json());" was above the webhook definition while it needs to be below of it, according to Shopify instructions.

```
app.post('/api/webhooks', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.process(req, res);
        console.log(`Webhook processed, returned status code 200`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Failed to process webhook: ${e.message}`);
        if (!res.headersSent) {
            res.status(500).send(e.message);
        }
    }
});

// And only then...
app.use(express.json());
```